# Kendoui ListView removes row in edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I am having an issue with kendouis' listview that if I edit a row the other one is removed from the attached datasource. This works fine when I edit first row but when I edit the other one then the first one is removed.

I have noticed that on edit of first row listview's edit function is called first but when I edit second row databinding, databound and then edit is called.

Here is code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

  transport: {
     read: function (options) {    
     options.success(lst);
  },
  update: function (options) {
      oThis.httpService.Post('api/DynamicPricing/UpdateDynamicItem', lst)
                            .success(function (data, status) {    
                                options.success(data);
                            });    
                    },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "Id",
                        fields: {
                            Name: { type: "string" },
                            CategoryF: { type: "string" },
                            DirectCost: { type: "number" },
                            IndirectCost: { type: "number" },
                            StrategyType: { type: "string" },
                            Value: { type: "string" },
                            OverridePrice: { type: "number" },
                            Current: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            list = $('#listcontent').kendoListView({
                template: kendo.template('<table cellpadding="3px" class="gridDynamicPricingContent"><tr> \
                                            <td width="100px">#:Name#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px">#:CategoryF#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px" align="right">#:DirectCostF#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px" align="right">#:IndirectCostF#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px">#:StrategyType#</td> \
                                            <td width="50px">#:Value#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px" style="text-align:right; padding-right:5px;" >#:OverridePriceF#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px">#:Current#</td > \
                                            <td width="100px"><a class="k-button  k-edit-button" href = "\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a></td>\
                                         </tr></table>'),
                editTemplate: kendo.template('<table class="gridDynamicPricingContent k-state-selected"><tr> \
                                            <td width="100px">#:Name#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px">#:CategoryF#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px" align="right">#if(DynamicPricingType==5){# #:data.DirectCost# #}else{#<input type="number" style="width:60px;" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:DirectCost" name="DirectCost" />#}#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px" align="right">#:IndirectCost#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px">#:StrategyType#</td> \
                                            <td width="50px">#:Value#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px" style="text-align:right; padding-right:5px;">#if(DynamicPricingType==4 || DynamicPricingType==5){#<input type="number" class="k-textbox" style="width:60px;" data-bind="value:OverridePrice" name="OverridePrice" />#}else{# #:data.OverridePrice# #}#</td> \
                                            <td width="100px">#:Current#</td > \
                                            <td width="100px"><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-update-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-update"></span></a></td> \
                                         </tr></table>'),
                dataSource: dataSource,
                selectable: true,
                dataBound: function () {
                    $('#listcontent').prepend(header);
                }    
            });//.data("kendoListView");
```

Comment: What does 'api/DynamicPricing/UpdateDynamicItem' return? Just the one item being updated, or the entire list of all items?

Comment: it returns all items and it is irrelevant because update is not called.

Answer (score 0):

I think your primary issue is that you have your `schema` inside your `transport`, at `dataSource.transport.schema`, but it should be `dataSource.schema`. So the DataSource does not see your schema.model specified. Without the model, it does not know what the `Id` field is, and without that, it probably wants to create new records on edit, instead of updating them.

---

Another possible issue might be that you have `schema.model.id` set to `Id` but you do not have that field in your list of fields in `schema.model.fields`. I would add Id to the fields.

---

Another issue is that the Kendo DataSource expects the server to return the 1 updated item, with the matching ID, not the entire list of items. If you can't change the server to only return 1 item, then you could change the logic in your `transport.update` function to only call `options.success()` with an array containing the 1 updated item.

---

Your templates also use `DirectCostF`, `IndirectCostF` and `DynamicPricingType` which are not in your `schmea.model.fields`.

---

I couldn't reproduce your server requests, but I made a jsFiddle that uses local data here: http://jsfiddle.net/rally25rs/Lo41dzwp/1/